# Combined Events Probability exam question

Tags: probability

Two fair coins are flipped at the same time. 
Work out 
P(two tails)
P(head and tail)

I know that the P(head) on one coin is 1/2 and same with tails but I don't know how to use that to answer this question.
I don't know if I should use the AND rule or the OR rule.

Thank You and Help is Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you refer to "*the 'and' rule*" and "*the 'or' rule*" I feel the need to remind you and emphasize the actual rules themselves.

If $A$ and $B$ are *independent* events, then the probability that both $A$ and $B$ happen will be $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.

If the probability $A$ and $B$ happen simultaneously is zero, then the probability of $A$ happening or $B$ happening will be $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)$.

Please be careful with the above two statements however as they are *only* going to be true in those restrictive scenarios.  If $A$ and $B$ are not independent, then the first will instead be $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B\mid A)$.  If $A$ and $B$ have a positive probability of occurring simultaneously then the second will instead be $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$

I cannot stress enough that you should *not* just assume "and" means that you can break apart as simple multiplication all of the time just as you should not assume "or" means break apart as addition all of the time.

---

On to your actual question.  Here, although the coins are being flipped simultaneously, in order to facilitate calculations we can pretend that the coins are able to be distinguished from one another... maybe one is a quarter and the other is a penny, or maybe one was painted blue and the other painted red... etc...

Now, the event "Both coins show tails" is equivalent to the event "The quarter shows a tail *and* the penny shows a tail."  These are independent events, so we can multiply the outcomes together.

You have as a result $Pr(\text{two tails}) = Pr(\text{Quarter is tails}\cap \text{Penny is tails}) = Pr(\text{Quarter is tails})\times Pr(\text{Penny is tails})=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$

On the other hand, the event "One coin (it doesn't matter which) shows heads and the other shows tails" is equivalent to "[The quarter shows heads and the penny shows tails] OR [The quarter shows tails and the penny shows heads]"

Since these cannot simultaneously happen, we can break apart with addition, and then afterwards break apart what remains by multiplication giving

$Pr(\text{One shows heads and the other tails}) = Pr(\text{Quarter is tails})\times Pr(\text{Penny is heads}) + Pr(\text{Quarter is heads})\times Pr(\text{Penny is tails}) = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$

You can skip ahead over some of the tedious steps in these calculations in similar questions by utilizing well known distributions, in this case for example the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) could be used and would be a much smarter approach than breaking apart manually in the event that we were throwing several more coins than just two.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that they're two different questions,

$$P(\text{two tails})=P(\text{tail})P(\text{tail})=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$P(\text{head and tail})=P(\text{tail})P(\text{head})+P(\text{head})P(\text{tail})=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I disapprove of the abuse of notation here and would find it much cleaner and clearer to use events which explicitly refer to the outcome of each individual flip.  Rather than $P(\text{head and tail})=P(\text{tail})P(\text{head})+P(\text{head})P(\text{tail})$ I think it is much better to use $P(X_1 +X_2 = 1) = P(X_1=1)P(X_2=0)+P(X_1=0)P(X_2=1)$ or something similar